# Why is MVC & Angular App failing to authorize?

Tags: angular, authentication, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app with an angular app inside it. The MVC runs server-side code and authenticates, saves a cookie. But when I switch over to the angular app it gives me a not authorized message when trying to get files from the server. What am I missing. I had assumed the cookie scenario would be automatic and I wouldn't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the way you launch your Angular app.

It may be on the "localhost:**4200** while your MVC app may be running on *other than 4200*, say **59970**. That's why your cookies won't be shared.

For that to work, you need to setup a proxy from your angular app to the MVC app.

Create a json config file named like "proxy.conf.json" at the root of your angular app

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:59970",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Now, update the package.json *start* script to

```js
"scripts": {
 "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
}
```